# How to avoid Runtime error in this coding challenge?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am completing [this HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-minion-game) coding challenge. Essentially, the challenge asks us to find all the substrings of the input string without mixing up the letters. Then, we count the number of substrings that start with a vowel and count the number of substrings that start with a consonant.

The coding challenge is structured as a game where Stuart's score is the number of consonant starting substrings and Kevin's score is the number of vowel starting substrings. The program outputs the winner, i.e. the one with the most substrings.

For example, I created the following code:

```
def constwordfinder(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return_lst = []
    for indx in range(1,len(word)+1):
        if word[indx-1:indx] not in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            itr = indx
            while itr < len(word)+1:
                return_lst.append(word[indx-1:itr])
                itr +=1
    return return_lst

def vowelwordfinder(word): 
    word = word.lower()
    return_lst = []
    for indx in range(1,len(word)+1):
        if word[indx-1:indx] in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            itr = indx
            while itr < len(word)+1:
                return_lst.append(word[indx-1:itr])
                itr +=1
    return return_lst

def game_scorer(const_list, vow_list):
    if  len(const_list) == len(vow_list):
        return 'Draw'
    else:
        if len(const_list) > len(vow_list):
            return 'Stuart ' + str(len(const_list))
        else:
            return 'Kevin ' + str(len(vow_list))

input_str = input()
print(game_scorer(constwordfinder(input_str), vowelwordfinder(input_str)))
```

This worked for smaller strings like `BANANA`, although when HackerRank started inputting strings like the following, I got multiple Runtime errors on the test cases:

```
NANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANANNANAN
```

I tried structuring the program to be a bit more concise, although I still got Runtime errors on the longer test cases:

```
def wordfinder(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return_lst = []
    for indx in range(1,len(word)+1):
        itr = indx
        while itr < len(word)+1:
            return_lst.append(word[indx-1:itr])
            itr +=1
    return return_lst

def game_scorer2(word_list):
    kevin_score = 0
    stuart_score = 0
    for word in word_list:
        if word[0:1] not in ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            stuart_score += 1
        else: 
            kevin_score +=1
    if stuart_score == kevin_score:
        return 'Draw'
    else:
        if stuart_score > kevin_score: 
            return 'Stuart ' + str(stuart_score)
        else:
            return 'Kevin ' + str(kevin_score)

print(game_scorer2(wordfinder(input())))
```

What else exactly should I be doing to structure my program to avoid Runtime errors like before?

Comment: What errors did you get? When I tried your code, `input()` failed and had to be replaced with `raw_input()`. And then there was an out of memory error...

Comment: Anyway, the number of substrings from a given letter is the length of a string minus the zero-based position of the letter in the string. Therefore both guys' scores can be calculated with just one pass through the string and no need to build up lists of substrings.

Comment: @KenY-N there is additional scoring for words that are substrings in given string

Comment: @ADG no ... Ken Y-N is right ... his solution passes all of hackerranks test cases (at least)

Comment: @ADG Yes, just created a HackerRank account, completed my example, and everything passed first time. The wording does sort of suggest that you should gather up substrings, but I think that's just to trick you and throw you off the track.

Comment: yeah its a trap im sure ... Im still not entirely why that solution you posted works... im interested enough to keep digging ... i found the same solution in someones github

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty partial solution based on my hints:

```
input_str = raw_input()
kevin = 0
for i, c in enumerate(input_str):
    if c.lower() in "aeiou":
        kevin += len(input_str) - i
print kevin
```

Basically, iterate over each character, and if it is in the set of vowels, Kevin's score increases by the number of remaining characters in the string.

The remaining work should be rather obvious, I hope!

[stolen from the spoilers section of the site in question]

Because say for **each consonant**, you can make **n substrings** beginning with that **consanant**. So for the **BANANA** example look at the first **B**. With that **B**, you can make: `B, BA, BAN, BANA, BANAN, BANANA`. That's six substrings starting with that **B** or `length(string) - indexof(character)`, which means that `B` adds `6` to the  score. So you go through the string, looking for each consonant, and add `length(string) - index` to the score.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Even less sure why the other non-answer got +2!

Comment: ok duh ... I finally found out why (I had to look up a spoiler) (possible -1 since it spoils the challenge a bit ...)

Comment: Wow. Now I feel like an idiot for not noticing that. Thanks for the answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your algorithm.You are finding all the Sub strings of the text. It takes exponential time to solve the problem. That's why you got run time errors here. You have to use another good algorithm to solve this problem rather than using sub strings.